# How do you find out if User exist Firebase Auth Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

How do I check if the user exist. I signed up a user through the Firebase SDK. I deleted the user at the Firebase console, and the user is still able to log in using the credentials. Its strange because after deleted in the console u can create a new user with the deleted email. While the user can still log in.

So I want to be able to check firebase through the SDK to find out if user exists so i can prevent or gain access through the app

Answer (score 0):

`pod 'Firebase/Auth'`
check out the related doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start
to be clear, you'll get `nil` value on the observation if an user with the specified ID is deautorised somehow. Something like `reference -> users -> auth.uid` if I remember all the stuff properly
auth.uid is `FIRAuth.auth.currentUser.uid` or whatever user you need to track. You have to share those uids somehow, I don't remember the firebase to have a built way to do that. However things could change since I've used it for the last time